# python dynamic array access [:0]

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to access an array dynamically in a loop like `array[n-i:-i]` and it works fine as long as `i != 0`. In case `i==0` I have `array[n:0]`, which I would expect to output `array` from n to the end but it returns nothing (`None` i guess).
How to archive the expected behaviour?

Comment: Why would slicing to `0` produce everything to the end? `0` is a valid index. Use `None` if you want to slice to the end.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `None` to slice to the end; Python then'll use `len(array)` as the endpoint. Use `or` to fall back to `None` when `-i` is `0`:

```
array[n-i:-i or None]
```

Numeric 0 is [considered false in Python boolean contexts](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). The [`or` operator short-circuits](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations); it returns the first operand if it is a true value, otherwise it'll evaluate the second operand and return that.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan: updated the answer with documentation links.